# PERMISSION DENIED when I try to load file from server

Tags: android, wamp

I need to load file in my android app from server ( local on wamp  test.json) but I get error **PERMISSION DENIED** . What mistake did I make ? Do I need to extra confihure wamp ? ( I can access - download that file from browser and from another blank android app with this same code in main activity )

```
try {

                            URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/test/test.json");


                            URLConnection urlconnection = url.openConnection();
                            long l = urlconnection.getContentLength();

                            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                            String line;
                            StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
                            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                            {
                               buffer.append(line);
                            }
                            in.close();


                            Object obj = JSONValue.parse(buffer.toString());
                            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) obj;

                            elements.load(buffer.toString());

                        } catch (Exception exc) {

                           exc.printStackTrace();

                        }
```

Comment: are you missing the `internet` permission?

Comment: Thanks !!! I am stupid, I forgot to add that !

Answer (score 2):

Verify that your AndroidManifest.xml contains permission for Internet Access :

```
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```